# How do I download all dependencies in advance?

Tags: java, maven

I'm writing a circleci script and I'd like to resolve all dependencies up front once, because I plan to run maven many times in this script.  I'd like to make this as fast as possible and I noticed that maven still reaches out to download poms, even if it has the latest dependencies.

To avoid downloading poms, I put ran maven with `-o`, offline mode.  But that caused errors about not having dependencies.  So then I ran this command to download dependencies and plugins in advance:

```
mvn dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugin
```

But after I run that, if I immediately run

```
mvn -o test
```

Then I get an error.  The error says this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project MyProject: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6 has not been downloaded from it before.

If I build the project locally with `mvn test`, it works fine.  If I run a `mvn package` on circleci instead of `mvn dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugin`, it works fine.

If I've downloaded all dependencies and plugins in advance, why am I getting the above error?  How do I resolve this?

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.app.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app Rest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-entity-filtering -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.maxmind.db/maxmind-db -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.db</groupId>
            <artifactId>maxmind-db</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.maxmind.geoip2/geoip2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b60</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b60</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b60</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b60</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app Rest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using snapshot versions?

Comment: @hoipolloi only of my own artifact.  Not for any of the dependencies or plugins

Comment: There are two things that you should to to avoid maven from reaching out to the network for newer versions. 1) ensure that version numbers in your pom dependencies are full and complete, and hard references (see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Version_Order_Specification). I can't tell what is in your pom because you have not posted a How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I neglected to mention the 2nd thing, which is to not to use any snapshot version specifiers.

Comment: How is maven supposed to know that what `SNAPSHOT` dependencies is and is not *"yours"* and why would it think those were not remote?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

`mvn dependency:go-offline`

> dependency:go-offline
>   Full name:
>
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:go-offline
>
> Description:
>
> Goal that resolves all project dependencies, including plugins and
>   reports and their dependencies.

But , before you should set the version for the dependency and compiler plugin into your pom:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: When I ran a mvn -o test after this, it gave me the same error as always: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project Blockfolio: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: ...`

Comment: I did a test with your pom: 1) mvn dependency:go-offline and 2) mvn -o test. It works without any errors...  Could you post more details about your project and your environment? Which version of Maven are you using?

Comment: @DanielKaplan, have you tried to set the dependency plugin version as suggested?

Comment: versions are important