# Can't download maven dependencies in offline mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I create a multi stage dockerfile to build the app:

```
########################################################################
#####                   Download dependencies                      #####
#####                                                              #####
########################################################################
FROM slimhs/maven-jdk-11:slim as dependencies

COPY jssecacerts $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

COPY pom.xml ./
RUN mvn -B -f pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:go-offline


########################################################################
#####                    Build the app with maven                  #####
#####                                                              #####
########################################################################

FROM dependencies as build

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN mvn -o -B -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml package


########################################################################
#####                    run the app                               #####
#####                                                              #####
########################################################################

FROM build
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/ego-api
WORKDIR /usr/src/ego-api

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/ego-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "./target/ego-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sc.bsc.sof</groupId>
        <artifactId>sof-spring-boot-pom-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ego</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.3.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <postgres.version>42.2.14</postgres.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <marvel-rocket.version>1.2.16</marvel-rocket.version>
        <flyway.version>6.5.3</flyway.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.socgen.marvel</groupId>
            <artifactId>marvel-rocket</artifactId>
            <version>${marvel-rocket.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DATABASE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flyway.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DEV TOOLS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I build the image I got those errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ego: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sc.bsc.sof:ego:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security
:jar:2.3.2.RELEASE, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14, org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3, net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.13, net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.13, org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final,
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.10: Cannot access sof-public (https://sof.sc/nexus/repository/maven-public) in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.3.2.RELEASE has
 not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mvn -o -B -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml package' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

There is a similar question mentioned by [How do I download all dependencies in advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453678/how-do-i-download-all-dependencies-in-advance)
 and even I found this ticket [go-offline / resolve-plugins does not resolve all plugin dependencies](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82) but still got the same error.

Comment: Please read the log output ... `Cannot access sof-public (https://sof.sc/nexus/repository/maven-public) in offline mode and the artifact`

Comment: I read it but `RUN mvn -B -f pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:go-offline ` does not download the plugins and dependencies and prepare them for offline mode?

Comment: it is the same issue mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453678/how-do-i-download-all-dependencies-in-advance and I'm asking how I can download everything from the beginning to not get this issue

Comment: You could try this plugin instead: https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin

Comment: For the people who downvote the question. Please give a comment why you downvote, it will help me first to know my mistake and the community to improve. Don't do that just to earn some points and get more reputation.

Comment: @NoDataFound i tried it but after downloading some dependencies I got `Failed to execute goal de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:1.2.5:resolve-dependencies (default-cli) on project ego: Execution default-cli of goal de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:1.2.5:resolve-dependencies failed.
 NullPointerException -> [Help 1]  `

Comment: Can't help you on this error, but I know both may fail while not hindering the build (after all, they download as much dependencies as needed even for case you would not use).

Comment: that's the problem there are some child dependencies or dynamic dependencies that maven download and that's why fail in offline mode because they are not downloaded before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NoDataFound who gave me a useful plugin, I tried [go-offline-maven-plugin](https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin) and I updated my pom to add a `dynamicDependency`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.qaware.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>go-offline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                <dynamicDependencies>
                    <DynamicDependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <repositoryType>PLUGIN</repositoryType>
                    </DynamicDependency>
                <DynamicDependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <repositoryType>PLUGIN</repositoryType>
                </DynamicDependency>
                </dynamicDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```